# JSON Data is not Showing in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I have some JSON data which i want to appear on google map. But the thing is its showing nothing. The JSON data will load from a server where the index file is also located. when i try to debug the problems i got some errors that i didn't understood. So, here is my data:

```js
  var map, infowindow; ////
       var json = $.getJSON( "file.json", function( json ) {

   function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
    ////
  };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
          
         var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          
          var responses = json.ResponseData;
          
         for(var i = 0; i <= responses.length; i++) {
              

    // Adding a new marker for the object
    var position =
      new google.maps.LatLng( responses.CoordinateY, responses.CoordinateX ); ////
    bounds.extend( position ); ////
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position, ////
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title: responses.BuildingName
    });
    
    // Adding a new info window for the object
    var clicker = addClicker(marker, responses.BuildingName); ////

  }  map.fitBounds( bounds ); ////
  
  // Adding a new click event listener for the object
  function addClicker(marker, content) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      
      if (infowindow) {infowindow.close();}
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      
    });
  }
     }        
         
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

```html
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB6U22yg_ty9a4LFvJi6E0rYCyGwYt04Xk&callback=json">
    </script>

   <script src="https:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

the json data file link is [JSON DATA](http://www.tripleclickstudio.com/json/file.json)

and here is the link of the html file [HTML](http://www.tripleclickstudio.com/json/json.html)

The thing is i want to show the markers on google map. The json file will be updating all time.

Thanks

Comment: What errors did you get? ("i got some errors that i didn't understood")  Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits those errors.

Comment: Hey I have given the link of the work on the post.There is one error that says "Invalid value error:json is not a function" and another one is "too much recursion" i don't exactly know what that is.

Comment: The information **in the question** needs to be complete. Once you fix your site, the errors will no longer be there.

Comment: @geocodezip Ummm. actually i have given all of the data that my site contains. and i couldn't figure out where i might have made the mistake. so, If you please check that out and tell me that would be very helpful.

Comment: It would be a good exercise for you to create a [mcve], your code has lots of errors in it. `json` not being a function only being the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback in your API load is incorrect. `json` is not a function.